# How to include empty classes and IDs in sass result

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, stylesheet, sass

I have just started using sass and still learning. I am using this command to generate css from sass:

```
sass --watch custom.scss:custom.css
```

It seems to remove empty classes and IDs. Is it possible to include them on the resulted css?

Comment: Try throwing in a CSS comment inside the class so that it's no longer empty.

Comment: WHY do you want to have them included? It's just unnecessary load you shift around.

Comment: so that it appears on firebug and i can add style from there and copy paste back to sass. i wanted this during development only not on the one that goes live.

Comment: Christoph, I am using a framework that requires empty CSS rule-sets for rich text editor formats. So they are, in fact, a necessary bloat until this framework improves its methods.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

SASS never compiles empty classes, as a workaround you can add a CSS comment inside the class with no rules, so it will be compiled.

```
.empty {
  /*I'm still empty*/
}
```

Comment: nice! that works if compression is not applied. that's good enough for me. thx.

Comment: If you use `/*!` instead of `/*`, this will work for compiling with compression. The exclamation mark makes sure the comment won't be stripped out.

Comment: I won't downvote because the answer's correct, but I reeeeally wanted to because of the first paragraph. It's obvious that empty CSS rule-sets have no value alone, but there are external tools or workflows that may require them. Please provide future answers without being patronizing.

Comment: @Waiting for Dev... i'm guessing he want's to keep them so he can quickly test styles in the browser. i do it so i can quickly develop a base style, then from there i'll iterate through sass builds. saves alot of time for me. its better than going in blind imo. there is so many gotchas and context related side effects in css it can be helpful to test in the browser.

Comment: I came across a reasonable  use case today: https://gist.github.com/Grsmto/7791840 This BEM approach is popular for of the reasons mentioned in the opening comment. However, the Sass fails to compile if a modifier's parent element is empty, as there is nothing for it to extend on Line 20.